# How to use nopCommerce plugin in our own created plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, nopcommerce

I am very new in nopCommerce. I want to create a plugin in which I want to use already created plugins like Payment, Invoice etc. But I don't know how to implement other plugins in my own plugin.

Can any one also tell me from where I can get the free plugins of nopCommerce. I need to use another login plugin in nopCommerce. So I need a free login plugin. Please let me know if any one knows about it.

Thanks!!